# Return range anlong with worksheet name from a UDF

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

I want to run a advanced filter. so i want to write a function as advancedfilter which will take three parameter as range(Listrange,criteria range and copied range)...But every time my range will be different .So at first i write a formula which return the range from worksheet name and other parameter (See below function for clarity).

```
Public Function ConvertRange(ByVal sh As Worksheet, ByVal StartingRow As Long, ByVal StartingCol As Long, ByVal TotalCol As Long, ByVal LastRow As Long) 
As Range
With sh

Set ConvertRange = .Range(.Cells(StartingRow, StartingCol), .Cells(LastRow - StartingRow + 1, StartingCol + TotalCol - 1))
End With
End Function
```

So this function returns the range but Listrng in one worksheet but Criteriarng and copied rng in another sheet..so along with range address i need find the name of the sheet..How can i do that?
AdvancedFilter Function:

```
Public Sub AdvancedFilter(Listrng As Range, criteriarng As Range, targetrng As Range)

'Set the target range where the unique values will be copied to.
Set targetRange = targetrng
'Calculating last non blank row of column A in Sh1 worksheet.
'Set the collection range from where the values will filter out.
Set rngCollectFrom = Listrng
'Use Advanced Filter
rngCollectFrom.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, criteriaRange:=criteriarng, CopyToRange:=targetRange, Unique:=False
End Sub

Public Sub M()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = Worksheets("Logical operation")
Dim sh1 As Worksheet
Set sh1 = Worksheets("Transaction")
Dim Listrng As Range
Dim criteriarng As Range
Dim targetrng As Range
Set Listrng = ConvertRange(sh1, 1, 1, 4, 22)
MsgBox Listrng.Parent.Name & "!" & Listrng.Address
Set criteriarng = ConvertRange(sh, 1, 13, 4, 2)
MsgBox criteriarng.Parent.Name & "!" & criteriarng.Address
Set targetrng = ConvertRange(sh, 2, 21, 1, 3)
MsgBox targetrng.Parent.Name & "!" & targetrng.Address
Call AdvancedFilter(Listrng.Parent.Name & "!" & Listrng.Address, 
criteriarng.Parent.Name & "!" & criteriarng.Address, targetrng.Parent.Name & "!" & targetrng.Address)
End Sub
Call AdvancedFilter(Listrng.Parent.Name & "!" & Listrng.Address, criteriarng.Parent.Name & "!" & criteriarng.Address, targetrng.Parent.Name & "!" & targetrng.Address)
```

It returns runtime error 424
i think i messed up with below line:

```
Call AdvancedFilter(Listrng.Parent.Name & "!" & Listrng.Address, criteriarng.Parent.Name & "!" & criteriarng.Address, targetrng.Parent.Name & "!" & targetrng.Address)
```

Comment: If you passed a reference to the range *rng.Parent.Name`.

Comment: @ComputerVersteher Can you explain it a little bit please?

Comment: Please add the code to the post as an edit rather than in the comment so that it is properly formatted.

Comment: @SuperSymmetry I edit the question..

Comment: I want pass these parameter in Advanced filter function
Listrng = Transaction!$P$1:$R$19
criteriarng =Logical operation!$M$1:$P$2
targetrng = Logical operation!$U$2

Comment: @ComputerVersteher sorry i didn't understand what you are trying to tell.

Comment: Ignore that! I made wrong assumtions on your needs. You just want to pass the Ranges and you are not used to do that with a reference. By passing that reference as parameter to function, the worksheet of the Range is included, as I rold you, because e-g- `Listrng.Parent ` returns the worksheet `Listrng` was created on. All that is done by the host app automatic, you don't have to worry.

Comment: But as chris neilsen noted, you don't define the workbook of those rannges explicit, so they use implicit ActiveWorkbook. That may cause confusion, if the active workbook changes for some reason.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your `code`, passing `Range` into `Public Sub AdvancedFilter()` is causing trouble. Hence instead of that, try passing `Range.Address` in the form of `String` into `Public Sub AdvancedFilter()`. Please refer below Code.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub M()

    Dim sh As Worksheet, sh1 As Worksheet
    Dim sh_Name As String, sh1_Name As String
    Dim Listrng As Range, criteriarng As Range, targetrng As Range
    Dim a As String, b As String, c As String
    
    Set sh = Worksheets("Logical operation")
    Set sh1 = Worksheets("Transaction")
    
    sh_Name = "Logical operation"
    sh1_Name = "Transaction"
    
    Set Listrng = ConvertRange(sh1, 1, 1, 4, 22)
    'Debug.Print Listrng.Address
    a = Listrng.Address
    
    Set criteriarng = ConvertRange(sh, 1, 13, 4, 2)
    'Debug.Print criteriarng.Address
    b = "'" & sh_Name & "'" & "!" & criteriarng.Address
    'Debug.Print b
    
    Set targetrng = ConvertRange(sh, 2, 21, 1, 3)
    'Debug.Print targetrng.Address
    c = targetrng.Address
    
    Call AdvancedFilter(sh1_Name, a, b, c)

End Sub


'No change in Public Function ConvertRange()
Public Function ConvertRange(ByVal sh As Worksheet, ByVal StartingRow As Long, _
ByVal StartingCol As Long, ByVal TotalCol As Long, ByVal LastRow As Long) As Range

    With sh
        Set ConvertRange = .Range(.Cells(StartingRow, StartingCol), _
        .Cells(LastRow - StartingRow + 1, StartingCol + TotalCol - 1))
    End With

End Function
    
'All variables passed as Strings instead of Range with small modification in Code
Public Sub AdvancedFilter(sh1_Name As String, a As String, _
b As String, c As String)

        Sheets(sh1_Name).Range(a).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
        CriteriaRange:=Range(b), CopyToRange:=Range(c), Unique:=False
        
End Sub
```

Please let me know your feedback.

---

Note : Please avoid multiple renaming of variables as you pass them from one Sub to another.

Comment: Hey it works and i don't need to pass the sheet name too..Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you don't need a `ConvertRange` function to create a range reference on a particular sheet, so get rid of it.  Note that a `Range` object refers to a range *on a specific sheet* and *in a specific workbook*.

Instead, just fully specify the required ranges (these are the ranges your code is creating.  It's not clear if these are the ranges you *intend*, so update if required):

```
Set ConvertRange = sh1.Range("A1:D22")
Set Criteriarng = sh.Range("M1:P2")
Set Targetrng = sh.Range("U2")
```

Note: all these are implicitly refering to the `ActiveWorkbook`.  You can (and should) explicitly specify the `Workbook` too:

```
Dim wb as Workbook
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
' or
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
' or
Set wb = Application.Workbooks("NameOfYourBook.xlsm")
```

And include it in the Sheet references

```
Set sh = wb.Worksheets("Logical operation")
Set sh1 = wb.Worksheets("Transaction")
```

---

Secondly, you've already specified the Parameters of `AdvancedFilter` as `Range`.  This is good!  You just need to pass *ranges*, not *strings*

Also, use of `Call` is redundant, and you should not use it (ever)

So:

```
Call AdvancedFilter(Listrng.Parent.Name & "!" & Listrng.Address, criteriarng.Parent.Name & "!" & criteriarng.Address, targetrng.Parent.Name & "!" & targetrng.Address)
```

becomes

```
AdvancedFilter Listrng, criteriarng, targetrng
```

Comments in your `AdvancedFilter` Sub suggest you want to manipulate the passed ranges before calling `rngCollectFrom.AdvancedFilter`.  That's fine if you do.  Otherwise you may not need the sub at all.

---

Your code, refactored

```
Public Sub M()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = wb.Worksheets("Logical operation")
    
    Dim sh1 As Worksheet
    Set sh1 = wb.Worksheets("Transaction")
    
    Dim Listrng As Range
    Dim Criteriarng As Range
    Dim Targetrng As Range
    
    Set Listrng = sh1.Range("A1:D22")
    Set Criteriarng = sh.Range("M1:P2")
    Set Targetrng = sh.Range("U2")
    
    AdvancedFilter Listrng, Criteriarng, Targetrng
    ' or
    'Listrng.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, criteriaRange:=Criteriarng, CopyToRange:=Targetrng, Unique:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: I use convertrange function as the range is now always "A1:D22" . it always change..so i can't specifically write it as "A1:D22".. I didnot specify the workbook as i am calculating this in the activeworkbook..But it's a good point to specify the workbook.Thanks

Comment: So, you need to create a dynamic range.  I understand that.  But a function like your "convertrange" is the _wrong_ way to so it.  I'd suggest you ask a new question,  describing what information you have to define the range you want.  Once you understand how to create a range reference,  my answer to this question will make more sense

Comment: I find my solution..Your code was good..I don't need use advanced filter function..and yes the range contains the sheet name too...Although it shows us "A1:D22" as address but it can differentiate between "Logical operation!A1:D22" and "Transaction!A1:D22" when it perform advanced filter..Thank you for your kind help..

Comment: @MDIsmailHosen, since you've accepted Puntal's answer I guess you happy with a string based solution to your range references.  In my opinion this is a terrible solution, and will only lead to a world of hurt.  Please, take the time to learn how to create range references properly

Comment: i want to acknowledge two anser but stack overflow discard one when i click to other....Your answer also solved my problem.Now i have three way to do the same work..Thank you...Can you provide me some good source for learning range reference properly..

Comment: I have write down three answer..Can you tell me which perform better..Right now three answer provide me the data i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Public Sub M()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = Worksheets("Logical operation")

Dim sh1 As Worksheet
Set sh1 = Worksheets("Transaction")

Dim Listrng As Range
Dim criteriarng As Range
Dim targetrng As Range
Set Listrng = ConvertRange(sh1, 1, 1, 4, 22)

Set criteriarng = ConvertRange(sh, 1, 13, 4, 2)
Set targetrng = ConvertRange(sh, 2, 21, 1, 1)

AdvancedFilter Listrng, criteriarng, targetrng ' removed Call as obsolete

Debug.Print Listrng.Parent.Name ' print name of sh1 "Transaction"
End Sub
```

Because `.Range` is a child of `.Worksheet`, `.Worksheet` is the `.Parent`of `.Range`
`Range.Parent` returns the reference to the worksheet and `Range.Parent.Parent` returns the workbook reference, because `Worksheet` is a child of `Workbook`.

Comment: Sorry it doesn't do what i want to get..Listrang in Sh1 but criteriarng & targetrng is in sh sheet..so i need to specify the sheet name too along with their range,,,I think?

Comment: You specified the worksheet by paasing it to `ConvertRange` as first parameter and as `Listrng`was created with passing `sh1` and the others with passing `sh`, this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Answer One:Using List range,Criteria range,paste range as a range and using UDF AdvancedFilter.

```
'Calling Sub
 Public Sub CallingSub()
'Declaration of variable as worksheet to contain the worksheet name.
Dim sh As Worksheet, sh1 As Worksheet
'Set the required worksheet
Set sh = Worksheets("Logical operation")
Set sh1 = Worksheets("Transaction")
'Variable declaration for finding the range from ConvertRange sub.
Dim Listrng As Range, criteriarng As Range, targetrng As Range
'Finding the List range from where data will be fetched.
Set Listrng = ConvertRange(sh1, 1, 1, 4, 22)
'Finding the criteria range based on which data will be fetched.
Set criteriarng = ConvertRange(sh, 1, 13, 4, 6)
'Finding the range where data will be copied.
Set targetrng = ConvertRange(sh, 2, 21, 4, 3)
'Calling the AdvancedFitler function.
AdvancedFilter2 Listrng, criteriarng, targetrng
End Sub
'ConvertRange Function
 Public Function ConvertRange(ByVal sh As Worksheet, ByVal StartingRow As Long, ByVal StartingCol As Long, ByVal TotalCol As Long, ByVal LastRow As Long) As Range
'Calculating range based on below worksheet.
With sh
    'Find the range based on provided data.
    Set ConvertRange = .Range(.Cells(StartingRow, StartingCol), .Cells(LastRow, StartingCol + TotalCol - 1))
End With
End Function
'UDF AdvancedFilter
Public Sub AdvancedFilter(Listrng As Range, criteriarng As Range, targetrng As Range)
'Use advanced filter based on data passed on this sub.
Listrng.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, criteriarange:=criteriarng, copytorange:=targetrng, Unique:=False
End Sub
```

Answer Two:Using List range,Criteria range,paste range as a range and using excel in  AdvancedFilter.

```
'Calling Sub
 Public Sub CallingSub()
 'Declaration of variable as worksheet to contain the worksheet name.
Dim sh As Worksheet, sh1 As Worksheet
'Set the required worksheet
Set sh = Worksheets("Logical operation")
Set sh1 = Worksheets("Transaction")
'Variable declaration for finding the range from ConvertRange sub.
Dim Listrng As Range, criteriarng As Range, targetrng As Range
'Finding the List range from where data will be fetched.
Set Listrng = ConvertRange(sh1, 1, 16, 3, 19)
'Finding the criteria range based on which data will be fetched.
Set criteriarng = ConvertRange(sh, 1, 17, 3, 6)
'Finding the range where data will be copied.
Set targetrng = ConvertRange(sh, 2, 25, 3, 3)
'Use advanced filter function in place..No need to use UDF(User Defined Function).
Listrng.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, criteriarange:=criteriarng, copytorange:=targetrng, Unique:=False
End Sub
'ConvertRange Function
 Public Function ConvertRange(ByVal sh As Worksheet, ByVal StartingRow As Long, ByVal StartingCol As Long, ByVal TotalCol As Long, ByVal LastRow As Long) As Range
'Calculating range based on below worksheet.
With sh
    'Find the range based on provided data.
    Set ConvertRange = .Range(.Cells(StartingRow, StartingCol), .Cells(LastRow, StartingCol + TotalCol - 1))
End With
End Function
```

Answer three: Using List range,Criteria range,paste range address as a string along with their sheet name and using UDF AdvancedFilter

```
'Calling Sub
 Public Sub CallingSub()
'Declaration of variable as worksheet to contain the worksheet name.
Dim sh As Worksheet, sh1 As Worksheet
'Set the required worksheet
Set sh = Worksheets("Logical operation")
Set sh1 = Worksheets("Transaction")
'Variable declaration for finding the range from ConvertRange sub.
Dim Listrng As Range, criteriarng As Range, targetrng As Range
'Variable declaration for containing the address of range along with sheet name.
Dim a As String, b As String, c As String
'Finding the List range from where data will be fetched.
Set Listrng = ConvertRange(sh1, 1, 1, 4, 22)
'Finding the address of range along with sheet name.
a = "'" & Listrng.Parent.Name & "'!" & Listrng.Address
'Finding the criteria range based on which data will be fetched.
Set criteriarng = ConvertRange(sh, 1, 13, 4, 6)
'Finding the address of range along with sheet name.
b = "'" & criteriarng.Parent.Name & "'!" & criteriarng.Address
'Finding the range where data will be copied.
Set targetrng = ConvertRange(sh, 2, 21, 3, 3)
'Finding the address of range along with sheet name.
c = "'" & targetrng.Parent.Name & "'!" & targetrng.Address
'Calling the AdvancedFitler function.
AdvancedFilter a, b, c
End Sub
'ConvertRange Function
Public Function ConvertRange(ByVal sh As Worksheet, ByVal StartingRow As Long, ByVal StartingCol As Long, ByVal TotalCol As Long, ByVal LastRow As Long) As Range
'Calculating range based on below worksheet.
With sh
    'Find the range based on provided data.
    Set ConvertRange = .Range(.Cells(StartingRow, StartingCol), .Cells(LastRow, StartingCol + TotalCol - 1))
End With
End Function
'UDF AdvancedFilter
 Public Sub AdvancedFilter(Listrng As String, criteriarng As String, targetrng As String)
'Here Listrng,criteriarng and targetrng contain their range address along with sheet name.
'Use advanced filter based on data passed on this sub.
Range(Listrng).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, criteriarange:=Range(criteriarng), copytorange:=Range(targetrng), Unique:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: Main coding principle is KISS and better readable code is simpler. Then go for reputaion and Chris explicit advised you what to do and why. Also if you have working code but want to improve that SO is wrong place, go for [codereview.se]!